# Replace a frame layout inside a Bottom Sheet Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I want to replace a frame layout inside a bottom sheet dialog with another fragment. I am getting the id of the layout properly but while replacing, it crashes. the crash occurs in the fragment manager class.

```
  container = (ViewGroup) mContainer.onFindViewById(f.mContainerId);
                            if (container == null && !f.mRestored) {
                                String resName;
                                try {
                                    resName = f.getResources().getResourceName(f.mContainerId);
                                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                                    resName = "unknown";
                                }
                                throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                                        "No view found for id 0x"
                                        + Integer.toHexString(f.mContainerId) + " ("
                                        + resName
                                        + ") for fragment " + f));
                            }
```

throws the "No view found" exception. Is it possible in a Bottom sheet?

Comment: I am also facing same issue while replacing frame layout inside bottom sheet dialog using fragment transaction. Getting illegal state exception : item view not found after on create of fragment. On create view is not even getting called.

Comment: If you found any solution for this plz let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the fragment transaction inside a Bottom sheet dialog, For that, you should use Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment

Comment: But `BottomSheetDialogFragment` creates a modal dialog. Is there an equivalent for a constant bottom sheet?

Comment: @Odys : what is your requirement. ?